# use information from ngFor on another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to capture data about the `ngFor` loop instance that is being rendered in the view, to then output it to a different view that renders extra information about the first information captured in the `ngFor` loop.

Example:

**.ts file**

```
user = [
  {name: "Lucho", lastname: "Pai"},
  {name: "Debora", lastname: "Melo"},
  {name: "Elba", lastname: "Lazo"}
]
```

**.html file**

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of users">
  <li> 
    Name: {{ user.name }}
    Lastname: {{user.lastname }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

That will render 3 , one for each user. I want to click in any of them and go to another view that shows me detail information about the lastname family. I.e., if I click in the "Elba" , I want to navigate to a full description of the "Lazo" family. So I need to capture that user information to  navigate and to then make a request to my database to get the "Lazo" family information.

I've been thinking about this some days, but I cant grasp the concept that I need to understand to do it. It's to abstract for me. Between input(), output(), viewchild(), etc, I'm just tangling myself.

I really hope I explained myself,
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dear Kaiser I think you can use the local storage as in this example

**first.ts**

```
//first component
//Inject Router in your constructor from 
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router:Router) { }
navigateToOtherComponent(user){
localStorage.setItem("user",user);
this.router.navigate(['/second.ts']);
}
```

**.html**

```
//first component
// Add Event (Click) on the <li> tag or add a button aside with your content

<li (Click)="navigateToOtherComponent(user)"> 
Name: {{ user.name }}
Lastname: {{user.lastname }}
</li>
```

**second.ts**

```
//second component
constructor() {
const user = localStorage.getItem("user"); 
}
```

Comment: I solved my problem with this approach. Thank you very much Gabr!

Comment: @Eng.Gabr Is there any other way besides `localStorage`. I would really like to know this.

Comment: You Can use shared service too

Comment: @Eng.Gabr Could you, perhaps, add that method with an example in your answer?

Answer (score 3):

you can pass the value of selected family to the child component using @Input like this

component.ts

```
selectedFamily:any;
```

html

```
 <ul *ngFor="let user of users">
      <li (click)="selectedFamily=user;"> 
        Name: {{ user.name }}
        Lastname: {{user.lastname }}
      </li>
    </ul>
<detail-component *ngIf="selectedFamily" [value]="selectedFamily"></detail-component>
```

detail.component.ts

```
@Input() value:any;
```

**UPDATE** :- If the you want to navigate to another route to display the detail of the family you can use parameter to pass the unique id of the familiy

e.g

```
 <ul *ngFor="let user of users">
          <li (click)="onFamilySelect(user)"> 
            Name: {{ user.name }}
            Lastname: {{user.lastname }}
          </li>
        </ul>
```

component.ts

```
detailUrl:string="details/"// example route
onFamilySelect(user:any){
    this.router.navigate(this.detailUrl+user.UserId)//assuming UserId is unique Id
    }
}
```

on the new component

```
ngOnInit(){
  let userId = this.route.snapshot.param['id'];
   //and get the detail from db by userid
}
```

on route.module.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'details/:id', component: NewComponent }
     ];
```

Comment: My other components isn't a child one. Thanks for you answer though

Comment: Check the update If you want to navigate to other url with the selected data

Comment: This solves my problem too. Thank you very much Hana.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your detail component has a route configured and is called details. Hence use this answer only if you are routing to the details component. If you are displaying the details on the parent component itself, use the answer given by someone else below.

In your list.component.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of users">
  <li> 
    Name: {{ user.name }}
    Lastname: {{user.lastname }}
    <button (click)="showDetails(user.name)">Details</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your list.component.ts

```
constructor(private router: Router){}

user = [
  {name: "Lucho", lastname: "Pai"},
  {name: "Debora", lastname: "Melo"},
  {name: "Elba", lastname: "Lazo"}
]

showDetails(user){
    this.router.navigate(['/details', { user: user}]);
}
```

In your details component this is how you receive the data:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.user$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.user = params.get('user');
    })
  );
  //Do something with this.user
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, after importing everything typescripts complains over `params: paramMap` It says: Argument of type '(params: ParamMap) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ParamMap, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'. MAYBE i'm not getting something with the $ sign you put in the `user` variable?? I don't understand what is the $ for.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the user object in a function and run the navigation logic based on that specific user. For example in the html file you can bind and event to the `ul`:

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of users">
  <li (click)="navigateBasedOnUser(user)"> 
    Name: {{ user.name }}
    Lastname: {{user.lastname }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then in the component, you can define `navigateBasedOnUser` function to navigate. For example:

```
user = [
  {name: "Lucho", lastname: "Pai"},
  {name: "Debora", lastname: "Melo"},
  {name: "Elba", lastname: "Lazo"}
]
navigateBasedOnUser(user){
// the user parametere here will have the user object of the `li` the user clicked on. you can access all the values of the user i.e. name, last name e.t.c.
 this.router.navigate(["detailsComponent",user.name])
}
```

Comment: Is there a way i can use `user.name` in my `other.component.ts`??? .. that is not a child component.